# Get "super(): no arguments" error in one case but not a similar case

Tags: python, super

```
class Works(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print([cls,args]) # outputs [<class '__main__.Works'>, ()]
        return super().__new__(cls, args)

class DoesNotWork(type):
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs):
        print([args[0],args[:0]]) # outputs [<class '__main__.doesNotWork'>, ()]
        return super().__new__(args[0], args[:0])

Works() # is fine
DoesNotWork() # gets "RuntimeError: super(): no arguments"
```

As far as I can see, in both cases super._new__ receives the class literal as first argument, and an empty tuple as the 2nd.

So why does one give an error and the other not?

Comment: You're not using `cls` from `__new__` in your `DoesNotWork`... (also - you really should be using `*args` in `super()` as well to keep signatures correct...

Comment: Im not explicitly giving `__new__` in `DoesNotWork` a concrete 1st argument, but the arguments `super()` is being passed are identical, so I dont understand the error. Using *args gives me `TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments` error though thats a seperate question.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `__new__` and not `__init__` - it looks like you're really trying to use the later...

Comment: No reason, I just to know why I get an error in one case and not the other.

Comment: In its other form (in non-classmethods), `super(cls)` is the same as `super(cls, the_first_argument_passed_to_this_function)`. I suspect something similar is happening here - `super()` is trying to default to `super(first_argument_passed_to_this_function)`, but `*args` and `**kwargs` don't count as a arguments (because they're a special case), so it fails.

Answer (score 21):

The zero-argument form of `super` requires that the method containing it have an explicit (i.e., non-varargs) first argument.  This is suggested by [an older version of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html?#super) (emphasis added):

> The zero argument form automatically searches the stack frame for the class (`__class__`) **and the first argument**.

For some reason this note was removed in later versions of the docs.  (It might be worth raising a doc bug, because the docs are quite vague about how zero-argument `super` works and what is required for it to work.)

See also [this Python bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue15753) (which is unresolved, and not clearly accepted as even a bug).  The upshot is that zero-argument `super` is magic, and that magic fails in some cases.  As suggested in the bug report, if you want to accept only varargs, you'll need to use the explicit two-argument form of `super`.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer, Python is so unfinished at times.

Comment: in my case, my class init function has the first parameter with `self` and the `super()` was working. then i added 3-10 lines of code before the call to `super()` and somehow that broke the `super()`. FWIW: my python class is running in a browser via `skulpt`... so my application is not traditional.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: If you want help with that you should ask a separate question.

Comment: @BrenBarn no i fixed the issue. i was reporting that i got the same issue... but in a different way.