# Why can't you omit the arguments to super if you add *args in __init__ definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(*args):
        print(super())

MyClass()
```

Why does this code raise `RuntimeError: super(): no arguments`? This is in Python 3.7.4.

Comment: There has to be a first argument to the method for ["new `super`"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) to work correctly, although it doesn't have to be named `self`.

Comment: Is "[because they say so](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)" enough reason? (I.e., the first argument *must* be a simple variable.)

Comment: `print(super(MyClass, args[0]).__init__())` works as expected, no need to explicitly name `self`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [PEP 3135](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/), which introduced "new `super`" (emphasis mine):

> The new syntax:
>
> ```
> super()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> super(__class__, <firstarg>)
> ```
>
> where `__class__` is the class that the method was defined in, and
>   **`<firstarg>` is the first parameter of the method** (normally `self` for
>   instance methods, and `cls` for class methods).

There **must** be a specific first parameter for this to work (although it doesn't *necessarily* have to be called `self` or `cls`), it won't use e.g. `args[0]`.

---

As to *why* it needs to be a specific parameter, that's due to [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b55b65638254aa78b005fbf0b71fb02499f1852/Objects/typeobject.c#L7940-L7975); per the comment it uses the *"first local variable on the stack"*. If `co->co_argcount == 0`, as it is when you only specify `*args`, you get the `no arguments` error. This behaviour may not be the same in other implementations than CPython.

---

#### Related

- [How is super() in Python 3 implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13126727/3001761)
- [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19608134/3001761)
- [Get "super(): no arguments" error in one case but not a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39312553/3001761)
- [Schrödinger's variable: the __class__ cell magically appears if you're checking for its presence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36993577/3001761)

Comment: What is the difference between `self` in `def my_function(self)` and `args[0]` in `def my_function(*args)` ? In the latter case, isn't `args[0]` the `<firstarg>` of the function? And how it is clear from PEP 3135 that `super()` won't work with `args[0]`?

Comment: @python481516 there's no difference between the actual argument values, `self` and `args[0]` in those two cases reference the same object, which is why `super(MyClass, args[0])` would work fine. You just don't get the "automatic" zero-arguments `super` usage without a separate, explicit parameter.

Comment: thanks, is it stated anywhere in PEP or other Python documentation that for `super()` to work `__init__` must have **explicit** first parameter or is it just something that developers know from experience?

Comment: @python481516 it's not documented any more explicitly than above, as far as I can find, but every single example in the docs (and that I've ever written) has the explicit `self`/`cls` so avoids the issue that way. I'll add a bit on why the implementation needs that.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first argument of `__init__` should be reference to a class instance. If you pass first `*args` instead some position argument, first argument becomes a tuple:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(self)
        print(args)
        print(super())

MyClass(1,2)
```

this code will show to the result like this:

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f84228ce3c8>  
(1, 2)  
<super: <class 'MyClass'>, <MyClass object>>
```

Where `<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f84228ce3c8>` is reference to the class instance. You can't trick the interpreter by passing first `*args`(tuple) or `**kwargs`(dict of named args) instead, because first argument can be just position argument

Comment: Isn't `def my_function(a, b, c, d, e, ...)` the same as `def my_function(*args)`? And what is the definition of the first argument of the function? In the latter case, is it `args[0]` or `args`?

Comment: @python481516 , it's not important how the function gets arguments from outside. What matters is how the function receives its inside. All positional arguments that are not explicitly specified as function parameters will come inside the tuple `args` , including the first one. but python expects the first argument to be a reference to an instance of the current class, not tuple. If first argument is tuple, interpretator raises the error