# Python super in local scope

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I can't figure out why `super().method()` cannot be called from local scopes:

Correct code:

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        print('hello')

class B(A):
    def method(self):
        super().method()

B().method()
```

Error:

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        print('hello')

class B(A):
    def method(self):
        def f():
            super().method()
        f()

B().method()
```

Error output:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sample.py", line 12, in <module>
    B().method()
  File "D:\sample.py", line 10, in method
    f()
  File "D:\sample.py", line 9, in f
    super().method()
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: already updated

Comment: Because it references the first argument to the function it's used in see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423665/3001761

Comment: Note that the problem is specifically with calling `super` with no arguments, not with using `super` at all.

Comment: Roughly speaking, `f` is defined "too late" for the *compiler* to determine what the arguments to `super` should be.

Comment: No, really, please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Are you not voting to close as a duplicate of your link for the same reason I'm not? (I think it's a good candidate, but I'm not willing to use my dupe hammer to close the question unilaterally.)

Comment: No, really, really, please update your question with the **full** error traceback.